# Android: MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA

Tags: java, android, android-camera, mediastore

Can any ony give me guidelines on how to find the directory my Android device stores its images takem from a camera;

In the following code snippet, I intend to get a list of files in  prior to launching the camera app. When returning from the camera app get a list of all the files in the same directory and process the newly added ones.

```
public void onBtnTakePhoto(final View view) {
    existingfiles = UploadImageService.getFiles(<IMAGE_LOCATION>);
    final Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA);
    startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);
}


public void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode) {
        case TAKE_PICTURE:
            List<String> newFies = UploadImageService.getFiles(<IMAGE_LOCATION>);
            newFies.removeAll(existingfiles);
            for (String newFile : newFies) {
                File file = new File(newFile);
                addImage( Uri.fromFile(file), PictureSource.CAMERA);
            }
            break;
    }
    // regardless of which activity, check that files exist:
    verifyFilesExist(images);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand it, you actually would have to launch your intent with the [`ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE) action (instead of INTENT_ACTION_STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA). Then, in `onActivityResult` you have to get the data from the Intent: there you will find the reference to the image.

Look at the examples given [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#intent-receive).

But as I look at your answer, you probably would find this more useful:

```
String[] projection = { 
          MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns._ID, MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA 
}; 
String selection = ""; 
String[] selectionArgs = null; 
mImageExternalCursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
           projection, selection, selectionArgs, null); 
mImageInternalCursor = 
           managedQuery(MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projection,
           selection, selectionArgs, null);
```

then

```
String filePath = 
            mImageExternalCursor.getString(mImageExternalCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(
            Media‌Store.Images.ImageColumns.DATA));
```

(since you don't actually want to take a new picture).